# How does one search in the Messages App on MacOS within one conversation

Tags: macos, messages

Is there any way to easily one search in the Messages App on MacOS within one conversation? Across "conversations?

"Find" seems more for finding participants in conversations.

Any easy way to export a conversation (or all conversations) to text files?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a "Search" or "Find" feature in the iMessages app for mac in specific conversations. Only all conversations.

CMD+F is the shortcut to search within the app.

To print/export a conversation, CMD+P will allow for a print view, but in the bottom left you can change from printing to saving as a PDF, etc.

Comment: print/export is relatively useless as it doesn't go back to the beginning of the conversation.

Comment: Have you tried scrolling back in conversation? I know iMessages sometimes doesn't load all messages so you need to scroll up to get them to load.